# Not able to iterate mongo object in python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to get the records (books), which are present the in Mongo DB collection "books". I am using pymongo and flask.

Below is my code. In the code, if I remove the query update line (`query.update({'author': 'sachin'})`), it works fine.

What is the problem while updating the query dict?

```
from pymongo import connection as pymongo_client
import urllib


def get_books(query, skip_val=0, limit=None):
    conn, client = _connect()
    if limit:
        result = client.books.find(query).skip(skip_val).limit(limit)
    else:
        result = client.books.find(query)
    conn.close()
    return result


def _connect():
    user = "root"
    password = "password"
    host = "172.17.1.14"
    port = "27017"
    db_name = "books"
    auth_database = "admin"
    if user and password and auth_database:
        uri = "mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (
            user, urllib.quote_plus(password), host, port, auth_database)
    else:
        uri = "mongodb://%s:%s" % (host, port)
    conn = pymongo_client.Connection(uri, j=True)
    db = conn[db_name]
    return conn, db

query = {'project_name': 'cricket'}

books = get_books(query)

query.update({'author': 'sachin'})

for book in books:
    print book
```

Comment: Hi Arun, could you please include an errors you receive, particularly a stack trace? The update could fail for any number of reasons, and you haven't given enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am not getting any errors. Problem is I got the list of books, After that I am trying to update the query. Please note that after the updation, the dict "query" is not used after that anymore in the code then why I am not able to iterate the books?

Comment: Sorry to paraphrase, but not sure I understand, do you mean that you are able to iterate over books, until you do `query.update`?

Comment: Yah Alex. Before the query.update I am able to iterate the books. But once after updating the query, Even the object "books" remains same. I am not able to iterate it further.